# What is the point of defining a calling convention?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
int WINAPI WinMain ( HINSTANCE instance, HINSTANCE prev_instance, PSTR cmd_line, int cmd_show )
```

WINAPI is a a define that looks like this:

```
#define WINAPI      __stdcall
```

why can't you just do:

```
int __stdcall WinMain ( HINSTANCE instance, HINSTANCE prev_instance, PSTR cmd_line, int cmd_show )
```

actually I think my problem is that I'm sort of confusing defines with typedef's. Can someone explain this to me? what does the define do and why can't you just write __stdcall in its place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `WINAPI` calling convention is not *guaranteed* to be `__stdcall`. Code that uses `WINAPI` will still be correct even when it isn't.

You *can* write the function as in your latter example, and it'd work fine - it's just not good practice and would not be portable to a platform where the calling convention is something else.

Comment: Well, actually, you are wrong. Because it is impossible to change this convention now. Imagine if microsoft suddenly changes WINAPI to __cdecl, then every program which was compiled with a previous version of Win Api headers will function incorrectly

Comment: It makes sense for different platforms though. Only x86 has `__stdcall`, so expect WINAPI to be an empty macro on ARM.

Comment: @kids_fox Obviously the binary wouldn't still be valid, but the code would.

Comment: @James, he's right about the convention not changing for x86 -- the assumption that the entire world is x86 is wrong though.

Comment: @SimonRichter, Thank you, I'm aware of this :) Given your clarification my answer is irrelevant now

Answer (score 4):

This was originally done during the switchover from 16-bit to 32-bit code. In the 16-bit version of `<windows.h>` it was:

```
#define WINAPI __pascal
```

WINAPI let you compile for either without modifying the source code. Of course, 16-bit Windows is no longer a factor (at least for most people), but it's still not worth changing all the source code to use `__stdcall` directly (especially since it could change again someday).

Answer (score 3):

You *can* just write __stdcall in its place, but don't. They've seen fit to #define WINAPI to __stdcall to make that opaque, which is just good programming practice.

Answer (score 2):

Also, back in the day, some Windows libraries used Pascal calling convention and other libraries used C convention. A preprocessor define helped gloss over that.

Answer (score 1):

Because WINAPI is a macro (well a #define anyway) it can be "pre-processed" to mean something else or even nothing at all.

That means you can write more portable code, as you can put in WINAPI when it is required by Win32 to mean __stdcall but, or if it is required in another environment to mean something else or nothing.